# Russian equivalent of the sarcastic expression "Trust me to ...!" or "Leave it to me to ...!"

Tags: выражения

I just said in conversation:

> **Как же типично для меня** потерять что-то важное перед командировкой!

I'm wondering if this works as an equivalent of the sarcastic expression "Trust me/you to (lose ...!)" or "Leave it to me/you to (lose ...!)" in English.

How do Russian speakers commonly express this idea?

Answer (score 3):

We may say the following.

> **Я так всегда: как** надо собираться, я теряю ключи. (or Я - как всегда...)
>
> **Это так на тебя похоже:** выехал из дому и забыл чемодан.
>
> **В этом он весь**, вечно забывает всё, что нужно.
>
> **Ну это же я**, положила на видном месте, теперь не могу найти.
>
> **Ничего удивительного**, **она может и голову дома забыть**.
>
> **Да как обычно: как** надо собираться, **так** у тебя ничего нет.

And also all the ways to express annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. This can be an equivalent of those expressions meaning "it's so typical of me to lose something important right before a business trip!"

As for the alternatives, here are a few:

> Мне что-то важное потерять перед командировкой - **как с горы катиться** (informal).
>
> **Мне только волю дай** что-нибудь важное перед командировкой забыть!
>
> **Мне ничего не стоит** потерять что-то важное перед командировкой.

Comment: not down-voting - because personal experience is irrelevant here however can not help but notice  - I've never heard "как с горы катиться" (though it's immediately obvious from context why it's used here)

Comment: @shabunc check this out https://otvet.mail.ru/question/94541973

Comment: @shabunc "personal experience is irrelevant here... however, I can't help but notice...". Ain't it funny?;-)

Comment: no, it's not - I'm a native speaker who never hear this phrase, it gives some hint on how often it used. On the other hand no native speaker can claim to be what we call in Russian , you know "истина в последней инстанции" - any personal experience is limited.

Comment: @shabunc please don't take it personally :-) I agree with you about "истина в последней инстанции". But I'm just saying that if you haven't heard an expression, it doesn't mean it's not natural Russian. In fact, Russian is spoken in so many countries, by millions of people. Can anyone say their knowledge is perfect? I doubt it. And yes, it's my personal opinion. By the way, I'm a native speaker too.

Comment: it's new to me as well, but it's well attested in Google, maybe it's regional, i'm familiar with synonymous ***как два пальца обоссать***, but it's vulgar, let alone *(как) не хуй делать*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка как два пальца обоссать is new to me... Unfortunately, (как) не хуй делать is not. I hope the OP will not choose this phrase from all the suggested ones. ;-)

Comment: @Enguroo it's not the first time you fetch an odd bookish idiom and put it in the first place. ))))) I wonder if you have really heard that in life. I've not.

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка and also euphemisms for that: как два пальца об асфальт (but don't use it in your TED talk)) ) , как нечего делать (quite neutral), запросто (an accepted variant).

Comment: @Enguroo let me join Elena in her question, i too am curious if you heard it being used in real life

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Yes, I really have. I swear! All my family have been using it forever. If fact, I wrote it first because I came up with this expression before I came up with the rest.

Comment: @Elena you are very attentive. Again you are accusing me of using something odd. But it's OK. To be honest, it's odd I seem to be the only person here who knows and uses this idiom)) Please see my reply to БаянКупи-ка's comment.

Comment: @Enguroo it reminds me of some families who emigrated a long time ago and preserved the language they had been used to. It usually sounds very nostalgic. Btw, I don't accuse you of anything, I just note that a foreigner is most unlikely to be understood if he used that idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

**I.** *these have undertone of disappointment and annoyance*

**А)** **`всегда/вечно я чего-нибудь/куда-нибудь/с кем-нибудь etc.`** `+ future perfective` or `present`

> Всегда/Вечно я чего-нибудь (да) (по)теряю перед командировкой.
>   Всегда/Вечно я куда-нибудь не туда заеду/заезжаю.
>   Всегда/Вечно я свяжусь/связываюсь с каким-нибудь жуликом.

**В)** **`всегда/обязательно/вечно я должен что-нибудь/куда-нибудь/с кем-нибудь etc.`** `+ perfective infinitive`

> Всегда/Вечно/Обязательно я должен чего-нибудь потерять перед командировкой.
>   Всегда/Вечно/Обязательно я должен куда-нибудь не туда заехать.
>   Всегда/Вечно/Обязательно я должен связаться с каким-нибудь жуликом.

**С)** **`я (просто) не могу, чтобы не`** `+ perfective infinitive`

> Я (просто) не могу, чтобы чего-нибудь не потерять перед командировкой.
>   Я (просто) не могу, чтобы не заехать куда-нибудь не туда.
>   Я (просто) не могу, чтобы не связаться с каким-нибудь жуликом.

**D)** **`если бы я не`** `+ past imperfective`, **`это был бы не я`**

> Если бы я ничего не потерял перед командировкой, это был бы не я.
>   Если бы я не заехал не туда, это был бы не я.
>   Если бы я не связался с жуликом, это был бы не я.

**II.** *these have undertone of irony*

**A)** **`для меня - пара пустяков/(да) я запросто могу`**`+ perfective infinitive`

**B)** **`я - мастер`** `+ imperfective infinitive`

> Я - мастер попадать в неприятные ситуации.

Comment: Ah, thanks. About my phrasing not being idiomatic, do you mean that the structure "Как же типично для меня + infinitive" sounds odd or rather that this phrasing is not a good equivalent of "Trust me/you to (lose ...!)"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens the structure itself is peculiar, but grammatically it's sound and its import is perfectly clear... a native speaker could say that but it's an ad-hoc variant, not a stable phraseologism